# Spring Boot returns weird JSON on '/'. Do you know what this JSON means?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

When I access my Spring Boot Application at `http://localhost:8080/` I always receive following JSON. I have no idea where this JSON comes from and I don't think I made a controller for this. Have you maybe seen something like this before? Does it have something to do with Swagger?

[image]

p.s. I'm using spring MVC and spring Security in my application.

This is my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    // Spring Boot
    //implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:${springBootVersion}"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"

    // Spring Cloud
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client"
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-config-client', version: "${springBootVersion}"
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix'
    compileOnly group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-configuration-processor'    
}
```

Comment: looks similar to this (https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api) to me, however it's weird that it's on the "/" can you share more of the code? maybe pom.xml/build.gradle?

Comment: As @62mkv mentions would clear it up seeing your dependencies. Looks like you may have a HATEOS dependency included.

Comment: Right, I added the build.gradle of the project now in the edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This response is provided by Spring Data REST (which you have included by using the spring-boot-starter-data-rest dependency).

Excerpt from the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.resource-discoverability):

> Resource discovery starts at the top level of the application. By issuing a request to the root URL under which the Spring Data REST application is deployed, the client can extract, from the returned JSON object, a set of links that represent the next level of resources that are available to the client.